# Anyone have issues with Eclipse over Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: eclipse, ide, remote-desktop

I have a very strange issue that I'm hoping someone can help me with.  I have various installations of Eclipse on my development machine at work. The one I primarily use is Weblogic WorkSpace Studio 10.2.  This installation, along with a few Pulse installations I have set up works fine when I'm logged into my computer physically.

However, when I try to log into the computer using Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection utility I get an error stating: "Could not create Java virtual machine." and then I get the lovely Eclipse error box which I personally can gather almost nothing from.

Even if you don't have the solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Justin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What ended up working for me was the memory settings for the JVM. Apparently the remote desktop connection, or some other setting in Windows, blocks off a fairly large amount of space. By reducing the heap size allocation for the JVM during Eclipse and server start-up I was able to get this working. As a side note, I had PLENTY of space that windows could have used, so I don't think blankly adding more memory would necessarily solve the issue. If you find another solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

•   We came across an issue when user RDC’s to a remote system where the OS is Windows 10 and has a running Eclipse instance, the Eclipse instance terminates

•   Eclipse is one of the IDE’s for Java

•   The issue is because of Windows 10 Exploit protection

•   Pre-requisite: You will need Administrative permissions for executing the below

•   Navigate to Settings -> Update & Security -> Windows Security -> App & Browser Control -> Exploit Protection Settings

•   Add the program to exclude as below

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

**P.s. As of Window 10 1909 MS security advisory mentions we can disable some exploit protections by default.**

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is permission related. take a look at similar issue that symantec has:

http://service1.symantec.com/support/ent-security.nsf/854fa02b4f5013678825731a007d06af/8ea1593f1d1fcee68025759a003d8403?OpenDocument

Try to see if you have same patches installed that causes the security issue. Also refer to application log to see if there is a more specific error. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I think issue happens due to Windows, not Eclipse nor JVM. There is still open [Bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543747) on the Eclipse side and [one of the comments](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543747#c103) state that Microsoft is working on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Windows Remote Desktop-ing into my dev machine at work (which had only one version of eclipse installed on it). I had no troubles.

Is it possible that your problems stem from multiple versions of eclipse running at the same time?

Also, have you tried a fresh install of eclipse on your dev machine?

If the above two suggestions don't work, then the only thing that I can think of is what Mohammad said: you might need to check your permissions.

I would check the system log if I were you: Start > run > eventvwr

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to look at is the .log file which is in your eclipse's metadata folder (found in your workspace at $WORKSPACE_ROOT/.metadata/.log).  If you post the stack trace that it generates upon initialization, we can give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am now experiencing this in Eclipse (the Oxygen release and Java 1.8.0_181). I previously had the same problem with another Java-based program (Oxygen XML/XSL editor - the product name is coincidentally the same as the Eclipse version). Last year the Oxygen support team answered that it may be a known problem in Java.

> Even without seeing a crash report, considering your sequence of
>   events, this seems like a known common cause of crash for the Java
>   runtime. Keeping Oxygen/Java running for a long time, until the screen
>   or video card enters sleep then connecting/disconnecting
>   screens/projectors or connecting/disconnecting RDP can trigger a crash
>   in the Java runtime. We keep updating the Java runtime (JRE) with each
>   new version of Oxygen, but so far the issue has not been resolved in
>   newer versions of the JRE.
>
> e.g. Java VM logged issue:
>   https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8153389